# how can i turn off the debug view in electron?i cant find any about it using google

Tags: javascript, electron

[image]

every time i run my electron app,it starts like this!
always turn the front-end elements view,how can i start my app without this show on GUI?
 besides,why it goes with black bg? it went well on chrome.
thank u，guys

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The black screen is probably due to the css files routes. Check them.

If you followed the starter electron tutorial, you are most likely calling `mainWindow.openDevTools();`. Remove that line and you will not get the console.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your code is calling [`openDevTools()`](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/v0.37.6/docs/api/web-contents.md#webcontentsopendevtoolsoptions).

Answer (score 1):

Just comment the below code

```
win.webContents.openDevTools()
```

to

```
// win.webContents.openDevTools()
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the bug was with npm caching some sort of preference. Even when I got rid of "openDevTools()", the problem persisted. To fix the problem, I removed my node_modules folder, and re-ran "npm install", and from there everything worked just fine.